Would antimatter weapons be considered nuclear weapons under international law?
Was debating whether this should go here or in worldbuilding, but this is a real legal question and there are already other hypothetical nuclear weapons questions here.
Scenario: some country/company figures out a way to efficiently produce and stably  contain antimatter. Any large quantity of antimatter is a bomb if you disrupt the containment. So this is functionally a nuke equivalent, whether deliberately or accidentally. Let's assume it's immediately weaponized, not as a city buster, but a very large conventional bomb equivalent that can be carried by a small drone.
Question: is this a nuclear weapon as far as treaties(NPT, Outer Space treaty, etc) are concerned? I've looked at their texts and was surprised that "nuclear weapon" never seems to be defined.

There is already a broad term that would include devices of this nature, they are referred to as Weapons of Mass Destruction. This language is used in at least some treaties and other documents that deal with this sort of thing.

Since "antimatter" may include free anti-protons & anti-neutrons as well as other bosons, and, although these are much smaller in mass, various fermions, you could not strictly define an "antimatter" device as a nuclear weapon. Fission and fusion of nuclei is not involved in this destruction.

As you point out, this would be a question of first impression (since it has never come up in real life), which has no textual definition in some of the main source to resolve it with a definition. There are some very good arguments for considering it to be a nuclear weapon (similar physical mechanism, similar real world effect), and pretty weak ones in the other direction (a desire to read a word very narrowly for some reason), but the question has no definitive answer. Some laws regulating, e.g., fissionable materials, however, wouldn't have any application to it since they're not used.

Matter-antimatter reactions are nuclear reactions
So, yes.

Mustn't a nuclear reaction involve a nucleus? I wouldn't think that certain types of matter-antimatter reactions, like electron-positron annihilation, would be classed as a nuclear reaction since there is no nucleus or  nuclides before or after the reaction.

this is not a nuclear reaction... it's the complete conversion of mass into energy.  Nuclear involves splitting nucleus (into multiple where the atomic weight is less than the single atomic weight... that's the mass that is converted to energy)  or fusing two nucleus', where 2 atomic weights become a single with a weight less than the two summed.  Anti-matter colliding with matter is total annihilation...  I don't know that it's ever been observed in something as large as an atom though...  might be more involved with time than with a nucleus.  So you could call it "particle reaction"

As a matter of strict physics, that's not quite true. For example, an electron and a positron (the anti-matter partner of an electron) can have an anti-matter annihilation with each other, but neither electrons nor positrons are found in the nucleus of an atom, and "nuclear" in the narrow sense, refers to the physics of the nucleus of an atom which is bound by the residual strong force a.k.a. the nuclear binding force. I still think it would be a reasonable interpretation in context, but as a straight matter of physics, matter-antimatter reactions are frequently not nuclear reactions.

though pretty outdated, here's Aasimov's observations: https://www.gutenberg.org/files/49821/49821-h/49821-h.htm#c40

Blindly guessing at answers outside of one's expertise yields an incorrect answer, again.

@browsermator Atoms formed from antimatter have been created, although they don't last very long before being annihilated.

Without any kind of source, being it physics textbook or law quote, this is useless.
